# Cannot monitor custom performance counters in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, performancecounter

I've created a couple of custom performance counters in our application. When I deploy the application to Azure I can see the counters being collected in the `WADPerformanceCountersTable` but I cannot get them to show up on the Monitor tab of the dashboard.

I'm using Azure SDK v2.7. I modified my diagnostics.wadcfgx to contain the following additional performance counters.

```
<PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Current" sampleRate="PT3M" />
<PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Applications Running" sampleRate="PT3M" />
<PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Ipseity\Average Aggregate Hydration Time" sampleRate="PT30S" />
<PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Ipseity\Number of Aggregate Hydrations / sec" sampleRate="PT30S" />
```

I don't actually need `\ASP.NET\Requests Current` or `\ASP.NET\Applications Running`, I just added them to see if I could get something to show up in the dialog when I select "Add Metrics."

Here you can see a small snippet of the `WADPerformanceCountersTable` showing that it is indeed capturing my custom counters in question.

[image]

I have configured the worker role for Verbose monitoring but when I go to the Monitor tab and click "Add Metrics" not only do I not see my custom performance counters but I don't see either of the other standard counters I added for testing purposes (i.e. `\ASP.NET\Requests Current` and `\ASP.NET\Applications Running`).

[image]

According to http://wacustomperfcounters.codeplex.com/documentation what I'm doing should work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue and a manual workaround is documented in the below article under the section "To Add custom metrics to the metrics table."

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-monitor/#how-to-customize-the-metrics-chart

> The following steps assume that you have turned on Verbose monitoring level and have configured your application to collect and transfer custom performance counters.
>
> To display the custom performance counters in the portal you need to update the configuration in wad-control-container:
>
> Open the wad-control-container blob in your diagnostics storage account. You can use Visual Studio or any other storage explorer to do this.
>
> Navigate the blob path using the pattern DeploymentId/RoleName/RoleInstance to find the configuration for your role instance.
>
> Edit the configuration file for your role instance and update it to include any custom performance counters. For example to monitor Disk Write Bytes/sec for the C drive add the following under PerformanceCounters\Subscriptions node

```
<PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
  <CounterSpecifier>\LogicalDisk(C:)\Disk Write Bytes/sec</CounterSpecifier>
  <SampleRateInSeconds>180</SampleRateInSeconds>
</PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
```

> Save the changes and upload the configuration file back to the same location overwriting the existing file in the blob.
>
> Toggle to Verbose mode in the management portal configuration. If you were in Verbose mode already you will have to toggle to minimal and back to verbose.
>
> The custom performance counter will now be available in the Add Metrics dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we've ever been able to see custom counters in the portal.  They (Microsoft) only visualize counters that they think are important.  Try [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) for more... comprehensive Azure monitoring *shameless plug*

Comment: According to http://wacustomperfcounters.codeplex.com/documentation (from 2013) it should work. Near the bottom is a section entitled "Showing Custom Performance Counters on Management Portal" and it has screenshots showing custom performance counters in the portal. Perhaps they removed this functionality at some point?